# what can be causing /etc/cron.daily/apt to hang?

Tags: apt, cron, amazon-ec2

Lately I've been getting a mail from the server every day,

Subject

```
Cron <root@host> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

Body

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt:
DB Update failed, database locked
```

If i just run the `/etc/cron.daily/apt` part it just stays there with no output, i tried running `tail -f /var/log/apt/*.log /var/log/syslog &` and then running `/etc/cron.daily/apt` but no output either

Which database is locked and by what, i'm able to do `apt-get update` successfully.

Did some updates yesterday and had to restart, so the microsoft fix wont work here (this has been going on since before the updates so not related)

What else can I look into?

This is a amazon instance incase it matters

Answer (score 8):

What really properly fixed this problem for me was uninstalling apt-xapian-index package. None of the other suggested fixes did anything in my situation.

You may read more details from my [little blog post](http://www.porotal.org/fixing-daily-cron-db-update-failed-database-locked-error-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks, I had the same experience—changing the timeout as in other answers didn't change anything except how long it took to give up.

I'd like to quote a bit from your blog post (the reason I clicked through): "it seems that Synaptic, the Ubuntu graphical package manager probably uses Xapian. On my Ubuntu server I don’t use Synaptic so I don’t care if the Apt Xapian index is not updated. The usual apt-tools should still work perfectly." As your post says, YMMV. Works for me, not using Synaptic.

Answer (score 4):

Long story short, change `RandomSleep=1800` to something more pleasent. I chose `RandomSleep=5`

ref: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2009-February/175474.html & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1071892#post_6747612

Comment: This did nothing to fix my problem, which is the same as the OP. If you look at the code, the RandomSleep time is used as a limit for the actual time, which is chosen nominally randomly.

Hmm. Looking at the code, there seems to be a bug. RandomSleep is possibly reset to either 1 or 0, by the apt-config call. (If it's even set, mine wasn't.) The apt call either stomps the variable, or does nothing to it. It doesn't actually act on it's value in a useful way.

Comment: It seemed to fix my problems for a few days which I think was coincidence more than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have multiple APT/DPKG instances running at the same time. If you run something that blocks apt-get like aptitude in GUI mode, and type `sudo /etc/cron.daily/apt` eventually it will fail with the same message.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Doesn't apply to those of us running Ubuntu servers without GUI but it's sure to be useful to someone.

Comment: @Vaz actually, it does, another example would be apt-cron or unattended-upgrades